# Giving Comment right to users with 1 reputation

Tags: support, feature-request

Is it possible to tweak when users are allowed to comment on a question/answer?

As a moderator approximately ½ of the edits I do, is moving answers to comments. This is because new rep 1 users are not allowed to leave comments with < 50 rep.

It is quite tiresome to do this again and again! Not sure what the reasoning behind this is either. If it is fear of rep 1 users spamming the site, they can already do this with an Answer!

Is it possible to tweak our reputation model on our site, so that rep 1 users can leave comments?

Comment: I totally agree Anders. I researched this a lot: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/570/why-i-need-so-many-reputation-points-to-create-a-comment

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if rep from other SE sites carried over sooner. I think I read that once you have 200 rep somewhere you start with a base of 100 on each site? It would be nice if that was 100 and 50 instead. Comment Everywhere is really the most annoying thing not to have access to.

Comment: That's true about the 200 rep - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation