# Can't answer, can't comment?

Tags: support

I was assisting a user recently when I was told by a moderator to keep my helpful comments in comments, but not in the answer field.

I think this might have been misinterpreted of how this systems works because:
- You can't comment unless you have a reputation of 50.
- you can't really gain reputation for giving a helpful response unless it was through an answer...

Should commenting be open with less barriers?

[Giving Comment right to users with 1 reputation](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/giving-comment-right-to-users-with-1-reputation)

Comment: Ahh we'll that's life then lol more work for you guys ;)

Comment: Answering is definitely more helpful than commenting, and that's why there is a reputation requirement. Keep posting good answers and you'll hit 50 rep in no time! :)

Comment: I'd comment back on that thread - but like I said, I couldn't. But if I set up my own answer, I can comment on my own rather freely. So it does have it's purpose.

Comment: I would also say, that once the answer is moved to the comment, if the OP responds back to the comment, the responder needs to then add yet another answer to the thread in order to continue. So your moderators have to continue to move those messages back into comment. I think it's just a work of workload, especially within 48 hours of the creation of the post. Probably makes sense on those that are getting dusty ;)

Thanks for your response.